# sql query for report - select min date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to create a report which displays the stats for data in a sql server table.The table columns I am interested in are searchTerm, dateadded.
Now I want to get the count of records for each searchterm but also display the earliest and latest dateadded for that searchterm.
for example:

```
select searchterm, count(*) as recCount from SearchTable order by searchterm.
```

will just give me the counts so I just need the dates and distinct records only.

Comment: Can you post the table definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    searchterm,
    MIN(dateadded) AS minDateAdded, 
    MAX(dateadded) AS maxDateAdded, 
    count(*) as recCount
FROM SearchTable 
GROUP BY searchterm
```

They GROUP BY will ensure that each row is distinct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MIN and MAX functions, plus the GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT searchterm, MIN(dateadded) AS earliest, MAX(dateadded) AS latest, COUNT(*) as recCount
FROM SearchTable
GROUP BY searchterm
ORDER BY searchterm
```